# Converting '[Arrray]' into just the array in jinja 2?

Tags: python, arrays, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I need to change an array string to an array in jinja2. This is my sql alchemy database model:

```
class Film(db.Model): 
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  images = db.Column(db.String(200))
  film-name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
  categories = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
  director = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
```

I store an string array in categories and need to access it in jinja2. 
The array looks like this `'['action','family','comedy']'`

I have tried `literal_eval()` however this can't be used in jinja2 as it gives an error. How can I change the string array to a direct array so I can for loop it in jinja2?

Do I need to change my database logic or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JSON [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)/deserialization.

#### serialization *(from array to string)*:

```
categories = ['action', 'family', 'comedy']
f = Film(categories=json.dumps(categories)) # '["action", "family", "comedy"]'
```

#### deserialization *(from string to array)*:

```
json.loads(f.categories) # ['action', 'family', 'comedy']
```

### edit

To answer your question about how to have it in jinja, one solution would be to add a property to the Model that deserializes the categories attribute like so:

```
class Film(db.Model): 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    images = db.Column(db.String(200))
    film-name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    categories = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    director = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)

    @property
    def categories_as_list(self):
        if self.categories:
            return json.loads(self.categories)
        return []
```

In the template: `{{ f.categories_as_list }}` *(assuming f is an instance of Film)*.

Comment: I do exactly that, and first serialize the array then store it as a string in the database. However if Iam trying to display all movies in the html, I query the database using Film.query.all() and pass it directly into jinja2. How can I deserialize it before hand?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6682251/ilko1810 I edited the answer to give a solution